# Laravel view.php use config::get variable in base_path

Tags: php, laravel, request, config, base-path

I am trying to do this in laravel 5.2 view.php (edit base_path to use a config variable in the string):

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Config;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Request;

return [

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| View Storage Paths
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Most templating systems load templates from disk. Here you may specify
| an array of paths that should be checked for your views. Of course
| the usual Laravel view path has already been registered for you.
|
*/

'paths' => [
    realpath(base_path('resources/views/layouts/' . Config::get('api.' . Request::get('domain') . '.layout'))),
],
```

But now I receive this error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'ReflectionException' with message 'Class log does not exist' in /Applications/AMPPS/www/loan/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php:734 Stack trace: #0 /Applications/AMPPS/www/loan/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(734): ReflectionClass->__construct('log') #1 /Applications/AMPPS/www/loan/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(629): Illuminate\Container\Container->build('log', Array) #2 /Applications/AMPPS/www/loan/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php(697): Illuminate\Container\Container->make('log', Array) #3 /Applications/AMPPS/www/loan/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(849): Illuminate\Foundation\Application->make('Psr\Log\LoggerI...') #4 /Applications/AMPPS/www/loan/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(804): Illuminate\Container\Container->resolveClass(Object(ReflectionParameter)) #5 /Applications/AMPPS/www/loan/vendor/l in /Applications/AMPPS/www/loan/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php on line 734

How do I fix this? Because everything I try doesn't work.
Thanks ahead of time!

Comment: Are you trying to serve different views for different Tenants in a SaaS model? I ask because I've been down this route many times, and I can tell you that this file is not where you want to be stuffing logic in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to move this logic out to your `ViewServiceProvider` instead of trying to do this directly in the config file, that's a big no no.

So what we're going to do is

```
php artisan make:provider MyViewServiceProvider
```

Which is going to result in a file existing at:

```
App\Providers\MyViewServiceProvider
```

Now we're going to open `config/app.php`. Find the existing `ViewServiceProvider::class` in this file and replace it with the namespaced path above. It should look something like this:

```
//the old Illuminate\View\ViewServiceProvider::class
App\Providers\MyViewServiceProvider::class,
```

Now inside of the `registerViewFinder()` function, we can overload our view paths.

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Config;

public function registerViewFinder()
{
    $this->app->bind('view.finder', function ($app) {
        $custom_path = base_path('resources/views/layouts/' . Config::get('api.' . $this->app->request()->get('domain') . '.layout')
        $paths = array_merge(
            [$custom_path],
            $app['config']['view.paths']
        );

        return new FileViewFinder($app['files'], $paths);
    });
}
```

Going this route will ensure that your path is observed first. If the view is not found in that path, then you can fallback to `Laravel`'s default view path.

**Edit**

It's important to note that your class needs to extend the default ViewServiceProvider, and that there are 2 other functions you must declare, the whole file should look like below:

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\View\ViewServiceProvider;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Config;

class MyViewServiceProvider extends ViewServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Bootstrap the application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        parent::boot();
    }

    /**
     * Register the application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        parent::register();
    }

    /**
     * Register the view finder implementation.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function registerViewFinder()
    {
        $this->app->bind('view.finder', function ($app) {
            $custom_path = base_path('resources/views/layouts/' . Config::get('api.' . $this->app->request->get('domain') . '.layout')
            $paths = array_merge(
                [$custom_path],
                $app['config']['view.paths']
            );

            return new FileViewFinder($app['files'], $paths);
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much!  I will try this now.

Comment: @Bryce I've made some updates to make the implementation a bit more clear for you.

Comment: Thank you for being so helpful... I have an error now stating this: "Call to undefined method Illuminate\Foundation\Application::request()"

Comment: @Bryce I'm sorry, I made a typo when writing it. You shouldn't call the `->request()` as a function as an accessor. Try removing the `()` so it's just `$this->app->request->get('domain')`

Comment: Well, that solved that issue.  We must be getting close!  Thank you once again, really, I don't know how I ever would have figured this out otherwise...  last error (hopefully): "Class 'App\Providers\FileViewFinder' not found" ... im looking into it, but perhaps you might know off hand.

Comment: Thank you so much! I got it figured out!  This is exactly what I needed!

Comment: @Bryce Glad you got that sorted out. Take care.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/119039/discussion-between-bryce-and-ohgodwhy).

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: yes. Add this to the top of the file:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Config;
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I added this, but now I have a much larger error.  Still stuck, unfortunately.  Any ideas?

Comment: That's more like another question, but you should be able to use `use Log;` at the top of the file. If that doesn't work, try `use \Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log;`

Comment: `use Log;` should work, per the documentation. Make sure you're using the right case. Can you provide the code where you're using the logger?

Comment: Please don't try to perform business logic in config files, that's what ServiceProviders are for.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [config](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/helpers#method-config)- and [request](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/helpers#method-request)-helpers in your app's config files.

```
'paths' => [
    realpath(base_path(
        'resources/views/layouts/' . config('api.' . request('domain') . '.layout')
    )),
],
```

Comment: I've tried that, that does not work, it returns nothing.